# How much radiation on the surface of the moon during a Coronal Mass Ejection (CME)?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, astrophysics, estimation, sun, moon

I'm writing a book set on the moon. A Coronal Mass Ejection (CME) as large as the Carrington Event hits it. Three astronauts are caught out during an EVA. They will  cover their rover in regolith to help protect them from radiation and hunker down during the worst of it before going back to base.

1. How much radiation might hit the surface?
2. Would the regolith get gradually 'sandblasted' off across the 2 days where the storm is most intense?
3. Would radiation linger on the surface even after the worst of the storm has passed? I would assume so.
4. Is there anything else I should consider?

The rover + regolith should provide some protection, but my goal/hope is for the astronauts to be hit with  2-6 Gy radiation.

Is this possible, or at least plausible ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The huge amount of background about your fiction story, while fun, is not relevant on a professional physics forum. I recommend editing your post to at least separate that off in its own “context” section so your question does not get closed.

Comment: I've shortened it for clarity. Should I edit it more?

Comment: It’s better, though you should still try to focus on a single question at a time. As it stands, it’s a little hard for anyone to answer everything in one shot.

Comment: Thank you. I definitely see that, but seems like it'd be more distracting to make a series of similar questions? I'd also be happy to speak to anyone via email if this is moving too far away from the purpose of the Stack Exchange. I don't want to be a bother; I'm grateful for any expertise and assistance.

Comment: The best intro to radiation effects on astronauts (of which I am aware) is at https://doi.org/10.1002/9781119815570.ch3.  Looks like some really strong SEP events could give your skin upwards of a few thousand cGy (i.e., few hundred Gy).  However, those same events would only impart less than 0.5 Gy to the internal organs.  This assumes the astronauts were shielded by ~0.4 g $cm^{-2}$ of aluminum.  For the most extreme events, however, even 20 g $cm^{-2}$ of Al will not save you (thankfully events of this magnitude are once per 1000 year events)...